# Remove focus from dynamically created button

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have added a button to the DevExpress extra bar like below.

```
    Dim bbiBtn As New DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem
    bbiBtn.Caption = "Delete"
    bbiBtn.Name = "bbiDelete
    bbiBtn.Tag = "Delete"
    bbiBtn.ButtonStyle = BarButtonStyle.Check
    barMain.AddItem(bbiBtn) 'barMain is  DevExpress extra bar
```

Now when I click the button and task inside the click event is performed but the button is still focused. I want this to be removed.
I tried making other fields like a label to be focused. I also loop through all item inside the bar and reset it and refresh like below.

```
 For Each btn As DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem In barMain.Manager.Items
      If btn.Name = "bbiDelete" Then
        btn.Reset()
        btn.Refresh()    
      End If
    Next
```

But none of this worked. Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this one fix your problem?

`ButtonName.focus()`

If not use this.

`ButtonName.Select()`

Add this code if after you created your button.

By this code you can set where you want to focus your button. Set focus on any type of button not the one that you dynamically created.

Comment: I will let you know when I test it. I am off of work for some days. Thank You

Comment: sure just comment if there is a prob